# iOS private/public data management and storage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, networking, core-data

Is it possible to display as one array objects retrieved from network and same model but retrieved from core data. Purpose is to have same data possible to be public (then retrieved from network) or private and then this data is stored locally in coredata model. Attributes/Properties will be the same for both.

I plan to display this as swiftUI view (if that matters)

After some search I came with idea to have one struct that based on its privacy property will be translated to core data class model or if public directly connected to networking layer?

for example (some pseudo swift ;) )

```swift
struct Note {
   let note: String
   let isPrivate: Bool

   func save(self) {
       if self.isPrivate { save to CoreData }
       else { send save request with use of networking }
   }
}

class coreDataModel: NSManagedObject {
   var note: String
   let isPrivate = true
}

struct networkingModel {
   var note: String
   let isPrivate = false
}

class modelManager {
   func joinData() {
       let joinedModel: Note = coreDataModel + networkingModel 
    // and so on to display that model

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this, first load the ui with the existing local data. At the same time, make a call to your api on a background queue. Once the api results are available, filter for duplicates, then persist it locally. Then the last step is to notify the ui to reload.

This pseudo-code is a bit UIKit specific, however the same logic can be applied to when in SwiftUI. You won't need closure, you will compute directly to your publisher object, and ui will react based any new emits.

```
/// you can have one model for both api and core data 
struct Note: Hashable { let uuid = UUID.init() }

class ModelManager {
    private var _items: Array<Note> = []

    var onChanged: ((Array<Note>) -> Void)? = nil
    // you might also have an init, where you can have a timer running
    func start() {
        loadFromCoreData { [weak self] (items) in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }
            self._items.append(contentsOf: items)
            self.onChanged?(self._items)
            self.loadFromApi()
        }
    }

    private func loadFromCoreData(completion: @escaping (Array<Note>) -> Void) {
        // background queue
        // logic to load from coredata.
        let coreDataResults: Array<Note> = []
        completion(coreDataResults)
    }

    private func loadFromApi() {
        // background queue
        let apiResults: Array<Note> = []
        compute(contents: apiResults)
    }

    private func compute(contents: Array<Note>) {
        let combined = zip(_items, contents).flatMap{[$0.0, $0.1] }
        let newItems = Array(Set(combined)) // set doesn't allow duplicates 
        // save to db

        // insert to new to _items
        _items.append(contentsOf: newItems)
        // sort maybe to place new items on top
        self.onChanged?(self._items)

    }

}



// usage of this object 
    let manager = ModelManager()
    manager.start()
    manager.onChanged = { items in
        // [weak self] remember of retain cycles
        // make sure you are on main queue when reloading

    }
```

Comment: Do I read properly? you suggest to store public model locally in the same core data  model as private one and then display whole as "local" data?

Comment: _items is not a core data model here, yep? I ask because of `// save to db` comment in `compute(...)` method. If I cache api responses I would not need to store remote data locally I think.

Comment: Note could be anything you like as long you conform to the desired protocol.

Comment: yep that is clear to me. I just want to be sure that _items as you defined as private could be also a public property which I could for example Publish as ObservableObject property to SwiftUI view. Am I right?

Comment: thank you very much for this example. I will really help me create this mixed data model